# Extension of Likelihood-density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference

Given an observation scheme, say $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ where $X_i$ evolves to one measure, one can define the likelihood function, a parameter dependend density of the form
$$
L_n:=L(X_1,\ldots,X_n\mid\theta)
$$
This is a density wrt to a  measure say $P^n$. Thus there exists a measure e $Q^n$, such that $L_n$ is the radon-nikodym-derivative. However, for assumptions about consistency of an estimator one lets $n\rightarrow \infty$ can we expect a measure $Q^{\infty}?$

Comment: I find this notation and language somewhat misleading.  Writing $\text{“}L_n(\theta)\text{''}$ would be better.  The likelihood function is a function of $\theta$ with the $X$s fixed. As a function of $\theta$ it is NOT a density. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I misinterpreted "consistency of an estimator" to be referring to Kolmogorov's extension theorem, as opposed to statistical consistency of an estimator, so what follows below is not right.

Usually the likelihood function factors into $L_n:=L(X_1\mid\theta)\cdots L(X_n\mid\theta)$.

In this case the associated measure of likelihood function on $Q^\infty$ will exist by virtue of the [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem), so long as your finite measure satisfies consistency conditions listed in the link.

Comment: Ah i see. But the factoring of the likelihood function is not really relevant for that argument of usung the kolmogorov extension theorem or?

Comment: @ziT: It's not required but it makes establishing consistency easier.

Comment: ahh ok. Ok my main question is solved. So thank you very much May i ask one last person question?; when considering general Markov-Processes we have also a product structure by the conditional densities. The consistency should be generally fullfilled or?

Comment: @zit: In general yes: any reasonable stochastic process will fulfill the conditions. Check out theorem 106 in this link for a general statement for markov chains: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/notes/lecture-09.pdf

Comment: I find this misleading because it fails to make clear that $L_n$ is a function of $\theta$ with $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ fixed, not a function of $X_1,\ldots,X_n.$ And it's not a density.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I'm not sure I follow, although I've added an edit to emphasize that it's the likelihood measure that exists. $\theta$ is a fixed parameter, and $X_i$ are random variables. e.g. if $L(x|\theta) = C_\theta\exp(-|x-\theta|^2)$, then $L$ is a function of $X_i$, and therefore a random variable. It's arguable that it doesn't have to be a density, but it's still a random variable that has an associated measure.

Comment: @AlexR. : That's wrong. For every tuple $(X_i, \, i=1,\ldots,n)$ there is a likelihood function $\theta\mapsto L_n(\theta),$ and that is a function of $\theta,$ not of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n). \qquad$

Comment: @AlexR. : And the part you added is wrong.

Comment: Everything about this answer is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I think I see your source of contention. I’m assuming that $L$ is arbitrary, e.g. independent of the $X_i$s. Whereas you’re (and possibly OP?) assuming that it’s literally the probability of the $X_i$s as defined by their density?

Comment: @AlexR. : It's the probability density at the observed $X$ values regarded as a function of $\theta$ with the $X$ values fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the answer by "Alex R." is wrong.

You have a family of probability measures parametrized by $\theta$ in some parameter space $\Theta.$

You have a joint density function $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto f_\theta(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ whose domain is a Cartesian power of the space in which $X_1$ lies.

You have a likelihood function $\theta\mapsto L_n(\theta) = f_\theta(x_1,\ldots,x_n).$

This is a function of $\theta$ with $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ fixed at the actually observed data values.

You have a measure $\pi(d\theta)$ of some kind on the parameter space $\Theta.$ Often this is the prior probability distribution of $\theta.$

Then the likelihood function $L_n(\theta)$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative with respect to $\pi$ of a measure on the parameter space, given by
$$
A \mapsto \int_A L_n(\theta) \pi(d\theta).
$$
If $\pi$ is the prior probability distribution of $\theta,$ then if one normalizes this measure by multiplying by a constant, then one gets the posterior probability distribution of $\theta{:}$
$$
\Pr(\theta\in A\mid X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n) = \frac{\int_A L_n(\theta) \pi(d\theta)}{\int_\Theta L_n(\theta) \pi(d\theta)}.
$$
If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots\mid\theta\sim\operatorname{i.i.d.}$ then (perhaps under some regularity assumptions?) the posterior probability measure will converge in probability to $\theta.$

Comment: At the risk of being charitable, I misinterpreted "consistency of an estimator" to be referring to consistency of Kolmogorov's extension theorem, as opposed to statistical consistency of an estimator.

Comment: @AlexR. : That's a weird spin to put on this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, as I'd gladly de-accept my answer if it was possible. Kolmogorov Consistency Theorem is what I'm familiar with.

Comment: @AlexR. : The only technical meaning of the term "likelihood function" that I know is what I gave in this answer.